# Appending array while using recursive loop in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion

I am working on [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) in Ruby and stop at n = 1.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
def collatz(n)
  arr = []
  if n == 1
    arr << n
    return arr
  elsif n % 2 == 0
    n = n / 2
    arr << n
    collatz(n)
  else
    n = (3 * n) + 1
    arr << n
    collatz(n)
  end

end
```

I want the code to return an array of all n values throughout the loop. 
For example, if I do `collatz(10)`, I wish it to display `[5,16,8,4,2,1]`

Right now it displays `[1]` for any input value. This is because after the first loop, it calls collatz(n), and the first line says `arr= []`, thereby resetting my array each loop.

How can I continue the method loop while appending my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add array to params as exampled:

```
def collatz(arr, n)
  if n == 1
    arr << n
    return arr
  elsif n % 2 == 0
    n = n / 2
    arr << n
    collatz(arr, n)
  else
    n = (3 * n) + 1
    arr << n
    collatz(arr, n)
  end
end

puts "#{collatz([], 10).join(', ')}"
```

result will the same as you wish:

```
[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1]
```

But remember: recurse is a evil!

and within recurse:

```
def collatz(n)
  arr = []
  loop do
    n = n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : (3 * n) + 1
    arr << n
    break if n == 1
  end
  arr
end

puts "#{collatz(10).join(', ')}"
```

Comment: Why is recurse evil?

Comment: recurse is evil because it limit your abilities with maximum call stack limitations. It (callstack limit) depends on your language and computer, but it not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

If n is 1 return it like `Array`.
If n % 2 == 0 use n / 2 else use (3 * n) + 1.
if n is now 1 return it like `Array` else define new `Array` with n value and call yourself with new n.

```
def collatz(n)
  return [n] if n == 1
  n = n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : (3 * n) + 1
  n == 1 ? [n] : [n] + send(__method__, n)
end
```

**output**

```
p collatz(10)
# => [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

I hope this helps